# How to fill a selected path with color in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, shapes, fill

I am new to Illustrator and I am editing artwork which seems that it is drawn by paths.

My problem is I am unable to fill the part which is selected in the below image:

[image]

How I can fill the shape with a color?

Comment: Have you tried changing the fill attribute in the options along the top? It's currently set to black.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like it isn't actually a stroke, but rather it is it's own shape (you can see on the left that it shows *filled* with black)

What you would need to do, is merge it with the shape. Use the *shape builder* to join it.

Select all, then just drag areas to merge.

[image]

---

You can now fill with any color you want.

There are many places where you can choose colors in Illustrator, my two favorite are:

**Swatches** (*Window* → *Swatches*) and **Color** (*Window* → *Color* or <kbd>F6</kbd>)

[image: Swatches panel]
[image: Color panel]